# How to make multipart HTTP POST request in Android 5.1?

Tags: android, http-post, android-5.1.1-lollipop

As of Android 5.1, HttpPost and HttpMultipart classes have been deprecated. What's the correct way now to make POST requests that include both file sending and post params? Working sample code will be highly appreciated.

Also, please mention if we need to add any third party libraries in libs folder.

Answer (score 0):

yeah Http Client is deprecated, you can use HttpURLConnection.

Example:

```
private void uploadMultipartData() throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        reqEntity.addPart("fileToUpload", new FileBody(uploadFile));
        reqEntity.addPart("uname", new StringBody("MyUserName"));
        reqEntity.addPart("pwd", new StringBody("MyPassword"));
        String response = multipost(server_url, reqEntity);

        Log.e("", "Response :" + response);
    }


    private String multipost(String urlString, MultipartEntity reqEntity)
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.addRequestProperty("Content-length", reqEntity.getContentLength() + "");
            conn.addRequestProperty(reqEntity.getContentType().getName(), reqEntity.getContentType().getValue());

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            reqEntity.writeTo(conn.getOutputStream());
            os.close();
            conn.connect();

            if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                return readStream(conn.getInputStream());
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "multipart post error " + e + "(" + urlString + ")");
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String readStream(InputStream in)
    {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                builder.append(line);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    reader.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
```

Comment: But MultipartEntity is also deprecated.

Comment: use MultiPartEntityBuilder with HttpURLConnection

Comment: replaced MultipartEntity with MultiPartEntityBuilder, but it generates errors like reqEntity.getContentLength() function not found etc.

Comment: You can remove that statement. Not needed.

Comment: `conn.connect();`. Remove that too. Completely on the wrong place. That it does not harm now.